# Unable to log into Maximo after installing demo database maxinst.bat

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, websphere-7, application-server, maximo

I am getting this message every time go to http://test-max75:9080/maximo/ui/

> BMXAA0025E - The method can not be called because application server
>   security is not enabled. Enable Application Server Security. For
>   details, see information on defining server security in the
>   information center.

I logged into [WebSphere console](https://test-max75:9043/ibm/console/logon.jsp) and checked to see if Application Security is enabled. It is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to a mismatch of settings in the database. Although the WebSphere setting is set for Application Security, the database value must also match.

From a SQL tool, run this command:

`SELECT PROPVALUE FROM MAXPROPVALUE WHERE PROPNAME ='mxe.useAppServerSecurity' ;`

If the value is 0, this confirms Application Security is not set to true on the database level.

1. You need to change this value to 1

`UPDATE MAXPROPVALUE SET PROPVALUE= '1' WHERE PROPNAME = 'mxe.useAppServerSecurity';`

2. Restart the Maximo Application Server

For WebSphere 7.0.0.15: System administrator > node agents > check on the node agent box > Restart all nodes

[image]